# Labeled break just after loop not working in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, break, labeled-statements

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        stop2: {
                System.out.println("Count");
                if (x == 2)
                    break stop2;
        }

        stop3: for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                System.out.println("Second");
                if (x == 2)
                    break stop3;
        }
```

While I was learning the labeled break in Java, I noticed that putting the label just before and after the for statement would have different results. In the code above, the for loop with *stop2* does not stop after printing "Count" 3 times while the other one does. Can somebody explain the difference between these two? I thought the labeled break breaks the body right after the label...

Comment: The first example isn't legal. I'm surprised it compiles.

Comment: @user207421 - Try it and see .... and check the JLS link in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought the labeled break breaks the body right after the label.

No.  It breaks the statement (or block) to which the label is attached.

Thus:

```
  for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
      stop2: {
            // stuff
            break stop2;
      }
```

breaks the body statement of the `for` loop, but

```
 stop3: for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
      {
          //stuff
          break stop3;
      }
```

breaks the `for` statement.

Contrast the above this with

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
      {
          //stuff
          break;
      }
```

An ordinary (non-labelled) `break` can only be used in a loop or a switch statement, and it breaks the immediately enclosing loop or switch.

This is what [JLS 14.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15) says about this:

> "A `break` statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the innermost enclosing `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement of the immediately enclosing method or initializer; this statement, which is called the *break target*, then immediately completes normally."
>
> "A `break` statement with label `Identifier` attempts to transfer control to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same `Identifier` as its label; this statement, which is called the *break target*, then immediately completes normally. In this case, the break target need not be a `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement."

Thus, the key thing in determining what a `break` statement (ordinary or labelled) does is what the *break target* is.

---

This is all a bit obscure ... and another good reason to use labelled statements only when they are absolutely necessary.  I cannot see the justification for using them in your examples (except as illustrations).  One of them *should be* written as an ordinary `break` and the other *should be* written as a `continue`.

But (for the doubters) both of those examples are valid, compilable Java code and both have well defined meaning according to the JLS.

Comment: Thanks, the example was just an illustration btw.

Answer (score 4):

You have the syntax incorrect (for your desired behavior) in the first example. This

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
stop2: {
    System.out.println("Count");
    if (x == 2)
        break stop2;
}
```

should be

```
stop2: for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    System.out.println("Count");
    if (x == 2) {
        break stop2;
    }
}
```

**or** just

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    System.out.println("Count");
    if (x == 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Since an unlabeled `break` applies to the first (that is the innermost) loop when no label is applied to the `break`.

Comment: 'Without a label' should be removed from this.

Comment: @user207421 How so? A `break` without a label, means the loop also does not require a label.

Comment: You're implying that if a loop has a label it isn't considered when finding the innermost. I'm sure you don't mean that.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you dont need a labeled break. 
in Java the break statement breaks the loop that contains it.
So your `stop2` code block can really be.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    System.out.println("Count");
    if (x == 2) {
        break stop2;
    }
}
```

An example of a labelled break would be this.

Consider you have a loop within a loop and on some condition you want to break out of the outer loop.
Example:

```
stop2:
for (int x=0; x < 5; x++) {
  for (int y=0; y<5;y++) {
    if (x == 3 && y == 2)  { //just making up some condition for the example
        break stop2;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        stop2: {
                System.out.println("Count");
                if (x == 2)
                    break stop2;
        }
```

In this case, when you break label stop2 the control goes back again to for loop and starts with the next iteration (x = 3).

```
        stop3: for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                System.out.println("Second");
                if (x == 2)
                    break stop3;
        }
```

In case 2, when you break the label stop3 the control doesn't go back again to for loop.